# Ruby OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError on Ubuntu 12.04.1 / Ruby 1.9.3p0

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, openssl, sinatra, ubuntu-12.04

This is a pretty long story... but it basically boils down to the same issue that everyone else seems to have had, except I can't seem to resolve it.

I am using EC2 ami-3d4ff254 which is Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS x64.  I am deploying [Githubs Janky application](https://github.com/github/janky) which requires Ruby 1.93, and is a Sinatra app.

My basic install procedure of dependencies in Ubuntu is

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install curl ssh git-core git build-essential zlib1g zlib1g-dev libyaml-dev libxml2-dev libc6-dev autoconf automake libtool make postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contrib libpq-dev ruby1.9.3 ruby1.9.1-dev rubygems1.9.1 ruby-bundler openssl
```

I have also followed directions [here](http://lenni.info/blog/2012/05/installing-ruby-1-9-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pengolin/) to ensure 1.9.3 is the default.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3 400 \
--slave   /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz ruby.1.gz \
                /usr/share/man/man1/ruby1.9.3.1.gz \
--slave   /usr/bin/ri ri /usr/bin/ri1.9.3 \
--slave   /usr/bin/irb irb /usr/bin/irb1.9.3 \
--slave   /usr/bin/rdoc rdoc /usr/bin/rdoc1.9.3 \

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gem gem /usr/bin/gem1.9.3 400

sudo gem install rubygems-update
```

Thats the basic setup of my environment.

Cmd line verification of tool versions

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

gem -v
1.8.11

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
```

Here are the contents of Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activemodel (3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activesupport (3.2.8)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.3.2)
    arel (3.0.2)
    broach (0.2.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nap (~> 0.3)
    builder (3.0.4)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    eventmachine (1.0.0)
    faraday (0.8.4)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    faraday_middleware (0.9.0)
      faraday (>= 0.7.4, < 0.9)
    hashie (1.2.0)
    hipchat (0.6.1)
      httparty
      httparty
    httparty (0.9.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml
    i18n (0.6.1)
    janky (0.9.13)
      activerecord (~> 3.2.0)
      broach (~> 0.2)
      mustache (~> 0.11)
      rake (~> 0.9.2)
      replicate (~> 1.4)
      sinatra (~> 1.3)
      sinatra_auth_github (~> 0.7.0)
      yajl-ruby (~> 1.1.0)
    json (1.7.5)
    mime-types (1.19)
    multi_json (1.3.7)
    multi_xml (0.5.1)
    multipart-post (1.1.5)
    mustache (0.99.4)
    nap (0.5.1)
    oauth2 (0.5.2)
      faraday (~> 0.7)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    octokit (1.4.0)
      addressable (~> 2.2)
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      faraday_middleware (~> 0.8)
      hashie (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    pg (0.14.1)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-protection (1.2.0)
      rack
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    replicate (1.5)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    sinatra (1.3.3)
      rack (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.6)
      rack-protection (~> 1.2)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)
    sinatra_auth_github (0.7.0)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      sinatra (~> 1.0)
      warden-github (~> 0.7.0)
      yajl-ruby (~> 1.1)
    thin (1.5.0)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    warden-github (0.7.0)
      json (~> 1.5)
      oauth2 (~> 0.5.2)
      octokit (~> 1.4.0)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      warden (~> 1.0)
      yajl-ruby (~> 1.1)
    yajl-ruby (1.1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  hipchat (~> 0.4)
  janky (~> 0.9)
  pg
  thin
```

The app is being run under Upstart (as configured by Foreman)

Everything seems to be working totally fine with the app, aside from when it must make external connections to https sites.  It dies with the dreaded `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed:`

I've tried exporting a variable to the certs file

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

I've tried a few monkey patch suggestions.

I can also connect to the site at the cmd line with openssl, so this doesn't appear to be a system problem, just a Ruby problem (as far as I can tell)

```
openssl s_client -connect my.jenkins.site:443
```

This is a bit of a cross-post, but there are a lot more details for this saga on the [Janky issue tracker](https://github.com/github/janky/issues/111), including the call stack of where Ruby blows up, etc.

I'm stumped if anyone has any great ideas!  (I guess the next option is to try using RVM, which I know nothing about).

Answer (score 0):

I think this boils down to 1.9.3p0.

As soon as I used RVM to install Ruby, and used a later version, my issues went away.

So the moral of the story here is, don't use the Ruby that ships with Ubunutu.

FWIW - If I had to do it all over again, I would use rbenv instead.  It's much simpler.  RVM is a bit of a bear to work with (especially through Capistrano deploys, where the deploy user isn't the same as the user running the app, etc, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#readme), very helpful.